# Is there an ADO.NET provider for Sybase IQ?

Tags: ado.net, sap-iq

I'm trying to build an application in visual studio and I wanted to know if there is an ADO.NET provider for Sybase IQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sybase IQ .NET support is provided by the SQL Anywhere.NET Data Provider.

See [SyBooks Online](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01087.1520/html/iqnew1520/CEGHAFJI.htm).

Comment: Thank you Vadim.  Do you know if there is a link where I can see all the sybase IQ features in .NET or is it the same as the features offered by the SQL Anywhere .NET Data Provider for SQL Anywhere databases?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any link that specifically discusses Sybase IQ feature mapping to their .NET provider. Are you concerned about the provider missing anything specific?